# Dial 7 digits in an area requiring 10 digits

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, phone-app

My area code(402) is going to be requiring everyone to dial 10 digits soon because we're getting an area code overlay(your next door neighbor could have a 531 area code). However, at first everyone will have a 402 area code.

I would like to only dial 7 digits, and for the phone to see 7 digits and prepend 402. So I would tap buttons for 867-5309 and it would dial as if I had tapped 402-867-5309. Is there a way to make my Incredible do this?

Comment: Do you really directly dial numbers often enough for this to be a problem? Surely most of your phone calls are made using pre-saved Contacts in the address book?

Comment: My old Palm Treo had a setting to do this.  You could tell it to prepend certain numbers on all 7 digit dials, and a different one on all 8 digit dails...  Unfortunately I don't know of anything in Android to do this.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I am directly influenced by my Palm Centro which has it in the same way that @Matt does.

Comment: My old pre had this too! oh Palm, why must you have been so horribly marketed?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Dialer One](https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.mek.DialerOne) app. It is a pretty good 'Phone' replacement app. Under 'Advanced Settings' there is an option to specify 'Phone prefix'. This prefix will be added when you long click the call button. I tested by setting the prefix to '402'. I typed '8675309' and then long pressed the call button. It prefixed '402' and the number became '4028675309'. You can press the call button again to call the number.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of overkill just for this, but if you're using Google Voice [GVoice Callback](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xinlu.gvdial&hl=en) is a great rules-based dialing app.  You can use regexes in the rules, so it would be easy to add a rule to prepend 402 to any 7 digit number.